# use range object as part of a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I pasted the entire macro below but this is the important part.

```
Range("B2:B10000").Value = Range("B2").Offset(-1, 1).Value    
Range("D2:D10000").Value = Range("D2").Offset(-1, 1).Value    
Range("F2:F10000").Value = Range("F2").Offset(-1, 1).Value    
Range("H2:H10000").Value = Range("H2").Offset(-1, 1).Value
```

It works as is except it is creating unnecessary data because I don't know how to use variable names in a range object. My ranges are currently hard coded such as ("A1:A1000"), when I would like it to be something like ("A1:A & LastRow).

Also I have to explicitly call out column names to copy because the range won't accept a variable name like ("currentColumn & 1:currentColumn & LastRow).

Is there a way to use a varible name as part of a range object so we can use them in loops?

```
Sub prepareWorkbook()

Dim wbk As Workbook
Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = wbk.ActiveSheet
Dim colx As Long
Dim ColumnCount As Long
Dim MySheetName As String
MySheetName = "Import"
LastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'copy the worksheet and rename it before editing
Sheets(1).Copy After:=Sheets(1)
ActiveSheet.Name = MySheetName

'identify the Id column and move it to 1st column
Dim answer As Variant
Dim IdColumn As Range
answer = Application.InputBox("Enter Letter of Id column")

If Columns(answer).Column = 1 Then
Else
    'cut Id column from current location and insert it at column index 1
    Columns(answer).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
End If

'trim the PartNumber column of any trailing spaces
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range("A1:A10000")
    c.Value = Application.Trim(Replace(c.Value, Chr(160), Chr(32)))
Next

' insert column every other column
' Loop through number of columns.
ColumnCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(1)) * 2

'step 2 means skip every other
For colx = 2 To ColumnCount Step 2
    Columns(colx).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Next

Range("B2:B10000").Value = Range("B2").Offset(-1, 1).Value    
Range("D2:D10000").Value = Range("D2").Offset(-1, 1).Value    
Range("F2:F10000").Value = Range("F2").Offset(-1, 1).Value    
Range("H2:H10000").Value = Range("H2").Offset(-1, 1).Value

wks.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
MsgBox ("Done")
```

End Sub

Comment: Couldn't you find the *PartNumber* column by its name and without user intervention?

Comment: Are you trying to put one value (e.g. `Range("B2").Offset(-1, 1).Value`) into a column of cells or do you want a row-by-row value transfer offset by -1 rows?

Comment: the partNumber field is not always the first column and it is not always named partNumber

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the you are running code in the Worksheet added here:

```
'copy the worksheet and rename it before editing
Sheets(1).Copy After:=Sheets(1)
ActiveSheet.Name = MySheetName
```

Also not sure what is the purpose of this code, nevertheless using it for the sample

```
Range("B2:B10000").Value = Range("B2").Offset(-1, 1).Value
```

Try this:

```
Dim lLastRow As Long
lLastRow = wbk.Worksheets(MySheetName).UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row

Rem This updates only columns B, D, F & H - adjust as needed
For colx = 2 To 8 Step 2
    With wbk.Worksheets(MySheetName)
        Rem Creates Range as Range(Cells(rIni,cIini), Cells(rEnd,cEnd))
        rem Corresponding code for "Range("B2:B10000").Value = Range("B2").Offset(-1, 1).Value" (see comment above)
        Range(.Cells(2, colx), .Cells(lLastRow, colx)) = .Cells(2, colx).Offset(-1, 1).Value
End With: Next
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Value = Range("B2").Offset(-1, 1).Value
Range("D2:D" & LastRow).Value = Range("D2").Offset(-1, 1).Value
Range("F2:F" & LastRow).Value = Range("F2").Offset(-1, 1).Value
Range("H2:H" & LastRow).Value = Range("H2").Offset(-1, 1).Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this answer won't be applied to your situation, I feel like this could help answer some questions you have in there.

When specifying a range, you can separate the column (letter) and row (number) and use your own variables.
In a for loop, this could look like

```
for i = 1 to 100
     Range("A" & i).Value = Range("A"&i).Offset(, 1).Value
next
```

You can also determine the number of the row of the selected cell using:

```
dim RowNb as long
RowNb = (ActiveCell.Row)
```

This also applies to columns, and can be used in a loop like I mentionned at the start.

Answer (score 1):

The one thing that was conspicuous by its absence in your description was any mention of the nature of the data in the worksheet. You mentioned `A1` briefly but your range value assignments started at row 2 so it may be inferred that row 1 contains column header labels.

```
Sub prepareWorkbook()
    Dim wbk As Workbook, wks As Worksheet
    Dim colx As Long
    Dim lc As Long, lr As Long
    Dim MySheetName As String

    Set wbk = ThisWorkbook    'no idea what this does
    Set wks = wbk.ActiveSheet 'no idea what this does
    MySheetName = "Import"

    'no idea what this does or what sht is
    'LastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    'copy the worksheet and rename it before editing
    Sheets(1).Copy After:=Sheets(1)

    With Sheets(2)
        .Name = MySheetName

        If CBool(Application.CountIf(.Rows(1), "PartNumber")) Then
            colx = Application.Match("PartNumber", .Rows(1), 0)
        Else
            colx = .Range(Application.InputBox("Enter Letter of Id column") & 1).Column
        End If
        If .Columns(colx).Column > 1 Then
            'cut Id column from current location and insert it at column index 1
            .Columns(colx).Cut
            .Columns(1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        End If

        'quickest way to trim trailing spaces is with Text-to-Columns, Fixed Width
        With .Columns(1)
            .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, 1)
        End With

        ' insert column every other column (working backwards toward A1)
        For lc = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column To 2 Step -1
            .Columns(lc).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        Next lc

        For lc = (.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1) To 2 Step -2
            'let's put the row-by-row value in instead of a single value into all cells
            lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, lc + 1).End(xlUp).Row
            With .Cells(2, lc).Resize(lr - 1, 1)
                .Cells = .Offset(-1, 1).Value
                .EntireColumn.AutoFit
            End With
        Next lc

    End With

    Set wbk = Nothing
    Set wks = Nothing

End Sub
```

Explanations as comments in code.